# How to implement a converter from string to Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a `ProgressRing` and a `TextBlock` and I am trying to implement this basic hack, which is to display both elements when TextBlock's Text gets assigned a value (anything other than null), else both elements should hide when TextBlock's Text is null.

My Xaml looks like below. TextBlock's *Text* is binded to `MessageForProgressRing` and its *Visibility* is binded to both `MessageForProgressRing` and `TargetNullValue`. Same for me `ProgressRing`:

```
    <StackPanel Panel.ZIndex="100" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <mahControls:ProgressRing Height="50" IsActive="True" Width="50" Visibility="{Binding MessageForProgressRing, TargetNullValue=Collapsed, FallbackValue=Visible}" Foreground="White"  Margin="0,0,0.2,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MessageForProgressRing}" Visibility="{Binding MessageForProgressRing, TargetNullValue=Collapsed, FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Then, in code behind I just trigger the property and assign it a value on some button event handlers:

```
private void closeApplicationButtonTask()
{
    ((CaptureViewModel)DataContext).MessageForProgressRing = "Closing... ";
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();
}
```

However, in my `ViewModelBase` (the parent of all my view models) it pops an error on `OnPropertyChanged` saying:

> Requested value 'Closing...' was not found.

I think I need a converter because *Visibility* is binded to `Closing...` right? If yes how can I achieve it?

P.S I couldn't do it in `OnPropertyChanged` because I don't see the `value` to assign it. Also I don't think it is a good idea since it gets called big time before, during and after the execution.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? A simple google search for 'wpf IValueConverter' would get you plenty of examples and tutorials like [this one](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html).

Comment: @Charles yeah but once I know what is the keyword (IValueConverter?). Thanks I am looking at it

Comment: My search was probably overly specific, the tutorial I linked to is the first hit for 'wpf converter'. You can probably forgive me for thinking you hadn't looked into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually prefer to solve this problem by having a boolean property in my view model (e.g. HasMessageForProgressRing or IsProgressRingVisible). It's usually a more general-purpose solution. Then you can use a [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).

If you truly want to implement a converter, just create a class that implements [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). The [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx) implementation of this should be a piece of cake for your simple use case. [ConvertBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback.aspx) isn't necessary in most cases (and won't be in yours). It would look something like this:

```
public class NullToCollapsed : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value != null ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool. I am doing that )))